# Transaction manager revert/rollback last commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I try to speedup my tests by putting test data from test case `setUp()` to `setUpClass()/teardownClass` class method, so it does not recreate same select only fixture for every test in test case.

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    plant.StuffFactory() #plant stuff with FactoryBoy
    transaction.commit()

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    session.query(models.Stuff).delete() # delete planted stuff
    transaction.commit()
```

But i don't like deleting stuff with session.delete on my own, because i use many models and don't want track what i planted. I want something like

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    session.clear() #delete all
    transaction.commit()
```

But `session.close()` or `session.remove()` will not affect committed data.
So i seek some way to "cancel" `setUpClass` `transaction.commit()` like i don't plant anything.

I try nested transactions and savepoints but again they works only if data not committed yet.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want things to be committed, simply don't call `transaction.commit()` :)

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    plant.StuffFactory() #plant stuff with FactoryBoy
    # you may possibly want to flush the session, so everything has proper IDs etc.
    DBSession.flush() 
    # let the transaction continue for the duration of the test

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    # let the database make everything as if nothing happened
    transaction.rollback()
```

This would require that none of your code under test does explicit transaction management (`transaction.commit()` \ `transaction.rollback()` in application code), but that's a bad practice anyway:

> As a general rule, the application should manage the lifecycle of the session externally to functions that deal with specific data. This is a fundamental separation of concerns which keeps data-specific operations agnostic of the context in which they access and manipulate that data.

Session Basics, SQLAlchemy Documentation (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html)

Comment: I'm new to ORMs. Why would it be a bad practice to call `session.commit()` in application code? How else would you commit anything? The SQLAlchemy docs seem to suggest using `commit()` even for "substantial applications": https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it

Comment: Ah, I think I know why. OP doesn't specify what kind of tests he's writing, and I'm guessing Sergey's advice is for unit tests, which I 100% agree with. Personally, I'm focused on writing integration tests, which will naturally run into a call to `commit()`, so I need a different strategy.

Comment: @mblakesley: I've added a quote from SA docs. For integration tests, I guess, you'd have to have a different strategy, such as deleting/recreating stuff in the db

Answer (score 1):

In `setUpClass()` you could create a save point as:

```
sp = transaction.savepoint()
```

then in `tearDownClass()` you could simply use:

```
sp.rollback()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You see, `sp` will become invalid after `transaction.commit()`, so if i try to do `sp.rollback()` it will throw `InvalidSavepointRollbackError: invalidated by a later savepoint`, maybe `transaction.commit()` create new savepoint, but then how to retrive it? I need rollback to pre commit state, before all planting.

Comment: You can declare it as class variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Comment: I am aware of usage like `cls.sp`
Just try this:
`sp = transaction.savepoint(); transaction.commit(); sp.rollback()`