# How to clear up test data from db after autotests using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm trying to make correct autotests in Python using SQLAlchemy to connect to postgre data base and setup test data for my tests in PyTest fixture. When tests ran, after `yield` I wanna clear all created in fixture data and close SQLAlchemy connection

That's how my fixture looks like:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def temp_db():
    session.begin()

    db_client_values = Client(
        *my new client values according to Client schema, that is imported from the file*
    )
    session.add_all([db_client_values])
    session.commit()

    new_client_id = db_client_values.id

    yield new_client_id

    session.rollback()
    session.close()
```

When I run tests with fixture like this, it works, data inserts to db, tests run successfully, but data stays there as there is no rollback() after yield.
I know, that rollback() is usually used for exception cases when there's an error while commiting data, but I found no other way to clear up data.

Can anyone tell me if there is other way to clear up data after autotests or why rollback in my code doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rollback() isn't doing anything because it is being called after commit(), so it won't affect the already commited data. You can call session.delete() to delete the objects, which would require another commit. [Otherwise, you may use flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032638/transaction-manager-revert-rollback-last-commit).

Comment: I added session.delete() and session.commit() after yield, but nothing changed. Talking about flush, it really deletes data after rollback, but API methods that I test don't see client I added by my script with flush. Seems that created client is visible only in my session, but not outside
So nothing really helped me yet. Seems like the only solution - deleting data "manually" by writing script that finds and deletes data after yield

Comment: Did you pass the objects to delete to session.delete()?

Comment: Oh, I didn't. Thanks